# When should we migrate vs. close and direct the asker to re-ask on the appropriate site

Tags: discussion, migration, moderation, abandonment

When a user asks an off-topic question before it's migrated we should look to see if they have an account on the site the question it to be migrated to.  If they do, then migrate it, if they don't then close the question and suggest that they ask it at the other site.

If the original asker cares enough to go make and account and link it up with their migrated question, they would probably be the type that would read the reason for closure, follow the advice and manually post it in the appropriate place anyway.  If they are more of casual visitor that probably will never return then this will cut down on the number of orphaned questions where the asker [image] is not a registered user.

I realize that questions can still be "[Answered](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/)" even when they are orphaned but it kind of bothers me to see the unregistered user icon.  Should we be trying to prevent the situation where answers don't have registered askers or am I focusing on something that doesn't matter?

Answer (score 2):

The point of Stack Exchange is to be a community resource. Just because the asker isn't here doesn't mean that others might have the same question. Unless the question is of extremely poor quality, you should vote to migrate to the appropriate SE site if one exists, since users of that site will probably find it interesting.